# NoMethodError Ruby setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and i've tried to set up a new project. I'm running Ubuntu 14.

These are my steps:

> 1. `rails new my_project -T` this created my new project.
> 2. `rake db:create` this created my database

Then i edited my Gemfile and deleted `gem 'sqlite3'`

```
group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
   end

   group :development do
     gem 'sqlite3'
   end
```

> 3. `bundle install --without production`
> 4. `rails g controller welcome index about` to create controllers

As last step i edited **config.rb**:

> 5. `root to: 'welcome#index'`

Now, when i try to go to localhost:3000/welcome/index i get the following error:

[image: Error]

**Why? It should display /welcome/index with the placeholder HTML.**

This is my Welcome Controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

Comment: I think problem in application.css. Can you show me css file.

Comment: It's all commented out... Only these i could activate: `= require_self` and 
`= require_tree` .

Comment: Show me Welcome controller.

Comment: @AmitSuroliya udated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application.css -
Remove :

```
*= require_tree .
```

and try. I am sure this problem appears because of css.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Why is it that commented out code affects the application?